# Android App not showing in Google play store search(Not in all mobiles)

Tags: android, google-play

I just uploaded the app to Google play store and this is the following link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1

When the user search this app in **play store it does not listed out my app** in certain devices only(Samsung Star Pro).This error message was shown

[image]

But when i tried to install this app from my Eclipse IDE means it was successfully installed.

Please provide some useful information about this issues..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="15"
    android:versionName="1.8" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       >
        <activity
            android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.MainCategory"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="True"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.service.MusicPlayService" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.helper.IncomingCallReciever"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.SocialMedias" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.ProgramList" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.Twitter" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.Contacts" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.ShareItWith" >
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.service.VersionCheckService" >
        </service>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.MoreAppsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio1.MoreApps"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance.Really looking forward to your suggestions

Comment: Show the manifest pls - it will help to see it.

Comment: when you upload the app - does it say to how many devices it is compatible? I had something like this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730620/bad-apk-when-using-bitcoinj-from-maven-central

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is a good idea to explicitly declare the phone features that your app requires, even though these features can be implied by the permissions you ask for.

It also makes it easier for you - because it forces you to think through each permission, and how it will affect different devices.

Read about this functionality here:

- [`<uses-feature>` on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

---

### Phone calls permission

It could be because of the "Phone calls" permission in your app - I see it is not available for my Nexus 7 either.

Your manifest will have the `CALL-PHONE` permission declared:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

This permission requires the device to have telephone features, by default. You can disable that requirement explicitly using:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

**Note:** in your code you might need to check before trying any of the telephony functions otherwise your app might crash.

---

### GPS permission

The Samsung Star Pro phone does not have a GPS.

Your manifest the permission for GPS:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

As above, this creates a requirement for GPS, which you can also try to turn off in a similar way.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

In this example, I require NETWORK location, but do not require GPS.

Comment: Yes thanks for ur answers.Now i updated my android App with the updated manifest file and uploaded to Google play store

Comment: Can u check my app now in your Nexus 7.

Comment: It is now available on the Nexus 7. Glad to be able to help.