# Supported devices 0 on Google play

Tags: android, google-play, signalr

I know similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices).
I uploaded an app to Google Play Store but it is incompatible with all the devices.
The app is actually a SignalR based chat application.
Check out this image
[image]

I am attaching the AndroidManifest.xml file.Any help would be appreciated.

```
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<supports-screens 
      android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I am using [signalr](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) library.I am using this library for a chat app in android.
I firstly developed eclipse based project and use the jar files.The app is working fine.

But when i try to upload the app to the Google Play.It shows me a message that your app doesn't supports any devices.
I even tried to upload the app without the libraries then it gets uploaded supports over 6K android devices.

As this library is updated for gradle for android.So i simply convert it into gradle project for android studio as well.Works perfectly but still won't supports any devices.

These are the jar files i am using in eclipse and android studio
[image]

Comment: can you show me the jar you use?

Comment: I have added the screen shot of jar files i am using.Thanks

Comment: Hm a screenshot is not really helping. Please look into the jar - I had it once that a lib contained 64bit native code - and then I had exactly the same behavior - I could execute on device - but play filtered to 0 devices

Comment: Can you please look.I have uploaded jar files.https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xjwl4jfc5rjaasi/AABFzzeJaH_ymea1j9lmtJFya?dl=0

Comment: or atleast elaborate the whole process how you overcome this bug

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730620/bad-apk-when-using-bitcoinj-from-maven-central
Dropbox wants me to register for downloading the file - I do not want dropbox

Comment: Download jars from drive.you can even upload items here.https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1pqesu2pQQ3fmNuVWIzSW13eHpTeHRTdEp6SHZYa0ZPYjZnYnBfd1JqVEI0QWRQa1Nqc1k&usp=sharing

Comment: you seem to have another problem - can you show the output of aapt d badging <your_apk>

Comment: image added in drive

Comment: hm this looks good - sorry then I have no more idea what this could be :-(

Comment: any solution that you might think will solve the problem.Thanks for the help so far. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem.Here two solutions have been posted.

> **Solution 1 : using aar files**

**Step 1**

First i convert my eclipse project into Gradle.

**Step 2**

Downloading  latest SignalR from this [link](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client).Generate the aar files.
Add these files as dependencies.

**Step 3**

Updated my Manifest file.I missed some permissions for location support. 
Now this is the new AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    android:maxSdkVersion="21" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"   />

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!--Only hdpi and xhdpi for normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>


<permission android:name="com.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Ofcourse it have application tag and activities as well.

> **Solution 2: using jar files**

**Step 1**

Create a directory named "libs" inside your main package and paste all the jar files.You can download jar files from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xjwl4jfc5rjaasi/AABFzzeJaH_ymea1j9lmtJFya?dl=0)

[image]

**Step 2**

Add dependencies in build.gradle of main package/app
[image]

**Step 3**

Now this how my project's main  build.gradle looks like.
[image]

**Step 4**

This is how my settings.gradle looks like

[image]

**Step 5**

After doing all these steps you still have import errors.So invalidate cache and restart

[image]

> **Final Output on Google Play**

Now it supports over 7K devices

[image]

Cheers :)

Comment: I followed these exact steps for solution number 2 and i am still having issues :(

Comment: please add a separate questions with the manifest file i will try to figure out the problem.Are you using signal r library ?

Answer (score 10):

I had faced same situation last week.

And I found the main problem is the "signalr-client-sdk.jar" was packed not correct for android.

> folder inside the "signalr-client-sdk.jar"

```
signalr-client-sdk.jar
|
|-lib
|  |
|  |-getLibs.ps1
|  |-getLibs.sh
|  |-gson-2.2.2.jar
```

These three file will be pack into apk "lib" folder.
It will work fine when your app with armeabi,x86,x86_64 native supprot library(*.so), but wrong with none. And make google developer console web to filter qualifier support device wrong.

> put this code to fix the problem

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'lib/getLibs.ps1'
  exclude 'lib/getLibs.sh'
  exclude 'lib/gson-2.2.2.jar'
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks man, you saved the day. They should have done a good job @ microsoft.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this issue by fixing the conflicting jar files. I posted them on github.
https://github.com/eak65/FixedSignalRJar

Comment: Thanks for this Ethan. Had the exact same issue with my app and this fixed the issue.

But can you please elaborate on what you exactly changed in these jars ?

Comment: @Knarf this error occurs because of conflicts with the gson dependencies. I resolved the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

We've had some success and been able to successfully integrate SignalR into our Android application and have an APK that operates correctly across multiple devices.  However, whenever we attempt to upload our APK to the Play Store it always reports 0 Support Devices.

This number returns again if we remove the SignalR Java/Android Cient .JAR Files.

Through discussion with Google Play Support, we were able to get the following insight:

> Thanks for your patience. My tools have confirmed that the issue is
>   being caused by the following which are declared as native platforms:
>   getLibs.ps1, getLibs.sh, gson-2.2.2.jar
>
> While we are able to determine the permission or feature that is
>   causing a compatibility conflict, we are unable to provide technical
>   development support to explain why the conflict is occurring, or how
>   to resolve the conflict. I'm sorry we can't provide a specific
>   resolution.
>
> The issue is definitely caused by using the libraries as native
>   platforms.

**Only a partial answer, but just want to share for anyone else that is facing this issue**

We have been able to get the APK to generate once we use .AAR file, but then the SignalR Connection no longer works.  Note sure how @Jhonny managed to get this working, but we have only been able to generate the one .AAR file (for android), but the general java module doesn't compile into .AAR.

Comment: You can download .AAR files from here https://app.box.com/s/k2m05ig0eg1qjey4ps6028ymtbdiijdc

Comment: Check this this link too.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611139/steps-to-get-signalr-working-in-android-studio/29628335#29628335

Comment: @Johnny , Really appreciate your comment/response to this.  This issue has been very challenging to get any insight on...! However, we had been able to compile the AAR for the one (signalr-client-sdk-android), but were unable to compile the AAR file for the other needed piece (signalr-client-sdk).  Do you have these other file, or were you able to get it working with just the one file?

Comment: I have added another solution for you follow the solution 2.Your problem will be solved.Added for you @SteelCityRKP2012..My app is available now in Google play by using solution 2

Comment: Thank you @Johnny, this is very helpful and provides clarity regarding this issue.  We've just had some success with compiling the JARs themselves within Gradle; however, we're still testing through.  This very helpful to see; much appreciated...!

Comment: SteelCity if you still have issues see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As default, any android feature has android:required="true". Hence, when you upload apk to Google Play, bots see android:required="true". It assumes that your app won't work unless that feature is available. Hence, you get this "0 devices supported".

Simply making android:required="false" solves the problem.