# Steps to get SignalR working in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, signalr

I'm trying to bring **SignalR** into my **Android Studio** project.

I successfully followed the tutorial on [getting started with SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr), so now I have a working `Hub`. The client in that tutorial is javascript, and I got it working ok in a web page (in Chrome) on PC AND on my Android phone over WiFi on my home LAN.

Then I went to go get the Android java client working. I already had an Android app project in Android Studio, which I want to make talk to that working `Hub` as a test, as the next step.

I downloaded the official Microsoft [java client for Android](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client), as a zip.

Then I extracted it and loaded it as a project into Android Studio. It builds with no errors.

Problem #1: This project only gives me an AAR, not a JAR. I have figured out how to use a jar in Android Studio, so if there's a way to create a jar at this juncture, I can probably make this work.

At this point I included the dependencies into my app project. The readme.md says to:

> Add the signalr-client-sdk.jar, signalr-client-sdk-android.jar gson
>   library as a gradle dependency to the project.

so I tried to follow that as closely as possible. Here's from my build.gradle:

```cs
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android-release.aar')
```

Problem #2: Having imported the aar as a module into my app project in Android Studio, it still does not see the necessary namespace to make the primary statement work. Here is the primary statement (the hello world of SignalR in Android, compiler-wise):

```java
Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
```

At first it wasn't picking up anything, then it picked up `import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Platform;` for `Platform`. It still does not have a clue what to `import` for `AndroidPlatformComponent`, so I'm stuck until I can get past this.

As you know there are a lot of files in Android Studio, and I don't want to just spew them all out here before I know which files you want to see. I'll add them as an edit if you tell me which files you want to see.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42527962/1770868

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well you can download the jar files from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xjwl4jfc5rjaasi/AABFzzeJaH_ymea1j9lmtJFya?dl=0)

**Step 1**

Create a libs folder inside your package and simply paste these jar files here.

[image]

**Step 2**

Now add "compile files" inside dependencies of build.gradle

[image]

Now after this press "Sync Project with Gradle file" [image]

**Step 3**

Even after syncing and importing jar successfully you still face some import errors etc.
Now try Invalidate cache and restart.After couple of times it will be fine and imports all the classes

[image]

**Step 4**

Now you will see the imports for  Platform.loadPlatformComponent(); without any problems

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh, one followup question. For future versions, I need to be able to make my own jar file without depending on a dropbox url. How would I do that?

Comment: wont  you run into this issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172454/android-market-this-application-is-available-to-over-0-devices

Comment: Awesome answeir, thnks!

Comment: @EthanKeiser i solved the issue by following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565203/supported-devices-0-on-google-play

Comment: Why I can't find the .jar file on the official page?

Comment: How did you generate the signalr-client-sdk-android.JAR, should it not be an AAR? I tried to compile and I got issues with android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient not being found.

Comment: @NathielBarros well they're not providing any compiled binaries (JARs or AARs). When compiling I get the signalr-client-sdk.jar, but I get an Android Archive (AAR) for the other. See my comment above...

Comment: @TalhaQ:- what are the original source of signalr sdk jar files, which you providing in dropbox ?

Comment: @TalhaQ when installing the apk to devices api 26, I got the INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS error. Even if I added splits - abi commands to the build.gradle it doesn't work.

Answer (score 18):

I got this working with just Android Studio and the files from the GitHub project.

Here's what I had to do, for posterity's sake.

1. Extract the [zip file](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/archive/master.zip) from [github](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/)
2. Open the contents in Android Studio as a separate project, and **Build**. It produces:

   - `signalr-client-sdk-android-debug.aar` in `java-client\signalr-client-sdk-android\build\outputs\aar`
   - `signalr-client-sdk.jar` in `java-client\signalr-client-sdk\build\libs`
3. Copy these 2 files into the `libs` folder of your app.
4. Go into module's `build.gradle` and add:

```cs
repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'signalr-client-sdk-android-release', ext: 'aar')
}
```

6. **Tools, Android, Sync Project with Gradle Files**, and when that was successful I did a **Build**.
7. Then finally, this line of code gave me the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> prompt to generate the `import`s for this line of code:

```java
Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
```

which gave me:

```java
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Platform;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.android.AndroidPlatformComponent;
```

**Whew!**

Comment: That's GREAT!..Can you please share with me the jar or aar files ? Thanks

Comment: @Johnny, ok, here's the [aar](https://app.box.com/s/k2m05ig0eg1qjey4ps6028ymtbdiijdc) from signalr-client-sdk-android commit `98ae5a47426da4d416a896c547080797bbafefae`

Comment: @toddmo you make no mention of referencing `signalr-client-sdk.jar` - is this something you had to do too ?

Comment: @wal
i found it is also required to add signalr-client-sdk.jar, becasue Platform class is available only in sdk.jar.  the answer is missing this.
1. places jar in project /libs/ 
2.  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')   under dependencies to include all jar automatically

Comment: @toddmo aar will give you AndroidPlatformComponent ref.  you still need to additional steps to include signalr-client-sdk.jar to your project to get Platform ref. If you extract aar, then extract classes.jar inside, you will find it is missing Platform class.

Comment: @Bamboo, I have redone / rediscovered the process and edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: This is better than downloading some Jar from dropbox. signalr-client-sdk-android-release is indeed an AAR not JAR.

Comment: What I'm wondering about is while I already had flatDir in my project's gradle, I had to duplicate it in the app's module gradle to get this to work! Any idea why?

Comment: @Mzn, no sir, it's been too long since I was doing this to say. Try removing from the project's build.gradle and see what happens.

Comment: It works when it's in the module's gradle and not in the project's gradle. It's already not in project's gradle. I think the explanation is simple: module gradle just doesn't inherit project gradle. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I also got this working with just Android Studio and the files from the GitHub project but my gradle dependencies are set like this:

```
            implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
            implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.aar')
```