# SignalR setup in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, signalr

I have developed a chatting application using signalR for android in eclipse by including 2 library projects. I want to port the application to Android Studio.
How and where do I include the jar files in Android studio. I have followed this link [Steps to get SignalR working in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611139/steps-to-get-signalr-working-in-android-studio). But I'm getting following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> Duplicate files copied in APK doc/allclasses-noframe.html
>       File 1: C:\AndroidStudioProjects\VConnectMD\app\libs\signalr-client-sdk-android.jar
>       File 2: C:\AndroidStudioProjects\VConnectMD\app\libs\signalr-client-sdk.jar

I have also added following

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

[image]

Can somebody help me with the setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thats almost means that you added the same library twice,
Try to download signalr-client-sdk-android.jar from the following link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8POMankZlWcNGZ1Zm9td3pDNVk

put it in your main app module build.gradle file

```
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
```

and sync your gradle files.