# SignalR events not coming in Android app built with TFS

Tags: android, android-studio, tfs, signalr, signalr.client

I am using SignalR for one of my android projects.
The same project source control is under TFS (Team Foundation Server).
I integrated SignalR as mentioned in this answer [Steps to get SignalR working in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611139/steps-to-get-signalr-working-in-android-studio)

When I build the app using Android Studio, SignalR events are coming in the app.
But when I build the app using TFS build system, the events are not coming in the app. Though I am getting logs in the TFS debug build that the connection is success. Events logs are not coming.

**What I tried:**
I tried replacing the signalr-client-sdk-android-release.jar with locally built aar. But the result is same.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you get any exception or warning during the build in the logs? And which TFS build system are you using? The old XAML build or the new vNext build?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Did not get any specific warnings or errors related to SignalR in the build logs. In TFS we have a Build tab and from there clicked on + icon and added the build definition. Below 'Build Definitions' left menu item, we have 'XAML definitions' menu item separately. So I guess this is vNext build.