# Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Action;

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the below error message when using Microsoft java client for signalR (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29639415/1095390)) and trying to build an apk from my source code in android studio.

**ERROR**

```
Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Action;
```

Some information of my tools

```
Android studio 2.1.2
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 23
gradle version : 2.1.2
repository: maven
```

I am new to android development and didn't know exactly what type of information may be needed to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the module-level build.gradle file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
android {
  ...

defaultConfig {
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...  }
dependencies {  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' ...}
```

In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication in

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: I couldnt undestand the second part of your answer

Comment: android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"