# SignalR with android(Java) having problem

Tags: android, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to make a realtime-communication between android app and a .net core server project.I tried a question in stackoverflow.

I followed this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573823/how-to-use-signalr-in-android).
In android side, I used these libraries

```
    implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
```

After that when try to install app,then it shown this message

[image]

Then I added aar file according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29639415/4122324).After that when try to build again another error shown,

```
Failed to resolved:signalr-client-sdk-android-release
```

After that I added this code into allprojects under repositories

```
 flatDir { dirs 'libs'}
```

Then that error gone and after try to install,another error occurs
 [image]

Please tell me how to fix this problem or if you know any article that covers realtime-communication between android and .net core.

Update:
I changed the signalR library in android side to this one

```
com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:1.0.0
```

Now again another error occurs,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Please tell me how to fix this

Answer (score 3):

It's looks like the links you referenced are a little out of date. They are for the depricated client that only works for classic ASP.NET. The SignalR team recently released a Java client for ASP.NET **Core** SignalR. Here are the getting started docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> if you know any article that covers realtime-communication between android and .net
>   core.

The doc I linked above is exactly that! Hope this helps!

Comment: ,thanks alot for your reply.I tried this.
then it's show an error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: ,Don't you have any idea?

Comment: A quick google search for your error sent me back to SO. This answer seems to be largely accepted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex