# No supported device for my Android app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I am aware this question is asked multiple times on stackoverflow, but the answers given in those posts don't help me out...

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="be.gps.android"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="0.0.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/TRL004451"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartUpActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.login.LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.useraccount.resetpassword.RequestResetPasswordActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.useraccount.resetpassword.VerifyResetPasswordActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.settings.ServerSettingsActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.settings.FilterActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.settings.DatePickerActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image: Screenshot of Google Play Developer Console]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with a library I was using (signalR).
This post had the exact same issue : [Supported devices 0 on Google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565203/supported-devices-0-on-google-play)

I just replaced the signalR jars with these https://github.com/eak65/FixedSignalRJar and now I have 9000 supported devices.