# 0 Supported devices in Google playstore

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-screen-support

I tried to publish the application in google playstore. But its shows 0 supported devices. Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.payxb.health"
        android:versionCode="01"
        android:versionName="1.0.0">

        <supports-screens
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="false" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
            ...
        </application>
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="25" >
        </uses-sdk>
    </manifest>
```

Please help me on this. What is the exact issue in this?

Comment: checkout this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565203/supported-devices-0-on-google-play

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I solved this problem. We have the dependency jar file. Inside the jar we have another jar files. As per the google developer console guidelines all the jars should be inside the libs folder. Otherwise it will consider as an native library jar.