# Zero supported android devices mystery

Tags: android, google-play, dexguard

I have been trying to solve this issue for about a month now and I cannot find any information that points to what might be causing my problem. I have checked and it does not seem to be one of the "uses-features" problems from what I can see.

I have posted a previous question related to the "Supported Android devices" details on the developer console that seems to be contradictory to me. [0 Supported devices or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106166/0-supported-devices-or-not)

Below is the output of aapt. Can anyone see anything there that would cause zero supported android devices? All assistance is appreciated. I have removed the "label" lines of the output.

```
package: name='com.telsortuk.telsort' versionCode='41' versionName='1.21' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2704002'
sdkVersion:'17'
targetSdkVersion:'22'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_LOGS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.NFC'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='com.android.vending.BILLING'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission: name='com.telsortuk.telsort.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
application-label:'Telsort'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-213:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-640:'res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='Telsort' icon='res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.telsortuk.telsort.MainActivity'  label='' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.bluetooth'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location.gps'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location.network'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.microphone'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.wifi'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'ca' 'da' 'fa' 'ja' 'ka' 'pa' 'ta' 'nb' 'be' 'de' 'ne' 'te' 'af' 'bg' 'th' 'fi' 'hi' 'si' 'vi' 'kk' 'mk' 'sk' 'uk' 'el' 'gl' 'ml' 'nl' 'pl' 'sl' 'tl' 'am' 'km' 'bn' 'in' 'kn' 'mn' 'ko' 'lo' 'no' 'ro' 'sq' 'ar' 'fr' 'hr' 'mr' 'sr' 'tr' 'ur' 'bs' 'cs' 'es' 'is' 'ms' 'et' 'it' 'lt' 'pt' 'eu' 'gu' 'hu' 'ru' 'zu' 'lv' 'sv' 'iw' 'sw' 'hy' 'ky' 'my' 'az' 'uz' 'fr-CA' 'lo-LA' 'en-GB' 'bn-BD' 'et-EE' 'ka-GE' 'ky-KG' 'km-KH' 'zh-HK' 'si-LK' 'mk-MK' 'ur-PK' 'sq-AL' 'hy-AM' 'my-MM' 'zh-CN' 'pa-IN' 'ta-IN' 'te-IN' 'ml-IN' 'en-IN' 'kn-IN' 'mr-IN' 'gu-IN' 'mn-MN' 'ne-NP' 'pt-BR' 'gl-ES' 'eu-ES' 'is-IS' 'es-US' 'pt-PT' 'en-AU' 'zh-TW' 'ms-MY' 'az-AZ' 'kk-KZ' 'uz-UZ'
densities: '120' '160' '213' '240' '320' '480' '640'
native-code: 'lib/classdictionary.txt' 'lib/dexguard-assumptions.pro' 'lib/dexguard-common.pro' 'lib/dexguard-debug-shrink.pro' 'lib/dexguard-debug.pro' 'lib/dexguard-library-common.pro' 'lib/dexguard-library-debug.pro' 'lib/dexguard-library-release-aggressive.pro' 'lib/dexguard-library-release-conservative.pro' 'lib/dexguard-library-release.pro' 'lib/dexguard-license.txt' 'lib/dexguard-release-aggressive.pro' 'lib/dexguard-release-conservative.pro' 'lib/dexguard-release.pro' 'lib/dictionary.txt' 'lib/filedictionary.txt'
```

Comment: Are all those permissions in the manifest?

Comment: I had a simmilar problem once ( a 64bit lib caused the problem ) - can you check if this is also your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730620/bad-apk-when-using-bitcoinj-from-maven-central

Comment: The last 2 permissions (cd2m,receive and C2D_Message) are not in my manifest! I did wonder about them but I am using FCM in my app.

Comment: I'll check the 64bit lib issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had included a dependency to "dexguard.jar" in gradle when I converted from Eclipse to Android Studio. I sent a query to Dexguard support and received the following reply:

There is no need to include the ‘lib/dexguard.jar’ in your app’s runtime dependencies - it only contains functionality that is needed at build time. It’s sufficient to only include ‘lib/dexguard_util.jar’, which bundles all DexGuard runtime functionality (in recent releases, this has been renamed to ‘dexguard-runtime.jar’).

Remove this line from your app’s build.gradle:

compile files('libs/dexguard.jar')

This is the reason why you are seeing all these ‘.pro’ files in your APK, and I expect it to also be the reason why the Play Store does not find any compatible devices.

Problem finally solved!